# Linux Kernel Invalidating TLB Entries

Tags: c, caching, linux-kernel, tlb

In the linux kernel, I wrote code that resembles `copy_page_range` (mm/memory.c) so copy memory from one process to another with COW optimization. The destination and source addresses can be offset by `PAGE_SIZE` and COW still works. I noticed, however, that in a user program when I copy from the same source address to different destination addresses, the TLB does not seem to be properly flushed. At a high level, my user level code does the following (I copy exactly one page, 0x1000 bytes on my machine, at a time):

SRC=0x20000000

1. Write to SRC (call the associated page `page1`).
2. Syscall to copy SRC into 0x30000000 in destination process. Now, src process address 0x20000000 and destination process address 0x30000000 point to the same page (`page1`).
3. Write something different to SRC (this should trigger a page fault to handle the COW). Assume source address now points to `page2`.
4. Syscall to copy SRC into 0x30001000 in destination process.

At this point, two separate pages should exist:
SRC 0x20000000 `page2`
DST 0x30000000 `page1`
DST 0x30001000 `page2`

I find that at step 3, when I write something different into src 0x20000000, no page fault is generated. Upon inspection, the actual page mappings are:
SRC 0x20000000 `page1`
DST 0x30000000 `page1`
DST 0x30001000 `page1`

In my code, if I call `flush_tlb_page` and pass the source address, the user code works as expected with the proper page mappings. So I am convinced I am not maintaining the TLB correctly. In `copy_page_range`, the kernel calls `mmu_notifier_invalidate_range_start/end` before and after it alters page tables. I am doing the exact same thing and have double checked I am indeed passing the correct struct_mm and addresses to `mmu_notifier_invalidate_range_start/end`. Does this function not handle flushing the tlb?

Ok, so literally as I finished typing this, I checked `dup_mmap` and realized that the primary caller of `copy_page_range`, `dup_mmap` (kernel/fork.c), calls `flush_tlb_mm`. I am guessing I should call `flush_cache_range` and `flush_tlb_range` before and after my kernel code. Is this correct? What exactly does `mmu_notifier_invalidate_range_start/end` do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, if you are doing something that changes page tables, you need to make sure that the TLB is invalidated as required.

`mmu_notifier_invalidate_range_start/end` are just calling MMU notifier hooks; these hooks only exist so that other kernel code can be told when TLB invalidation is happening.  The only places that set up MMU notifiers are

- KVM (hardware assisted virtualization) uses them to handle swapping out pages; it needs to know about host TLB invalidations to keep the virtualized guest MMU in sync with the host.
- GRU (driver for specialized hardware in huge SGI systems) uses MMU notifiers to keep the mapping tables in the GRU hardware in sync with the CPU MMU.

But pretty much any place that you are calling MMU notifier hooks, you should also be calling TLB shootdown functions if the kernel is not already doing it for you.

Comment: can you plz explain a little bit about mmu_notifiers? I am stuck on whether these hooks are used only by kernel to inform kvm/vmm or vice versa is also true? whether these hooks are used for all pages or only those pages which are being used by VMM. if yes how these are registered?